# Sending message to Azure Service Bus from POSTMAN nodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I have been trying to send a sample message to Azure Service Bus Topic from POSTMAN, But it came with an unusual error. Here my doubt is, I am generating the SAS token using NodeJs own 'Buffer' rather than 'utf8' module. Can that be a reason Why I am getting **'The specified HTTP verb (POST) is not valid.'**. Here is my snippet to generate the SAS token.

```
*function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) {
    if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) {
        throw "Missing required parameter";
    }
    console.log('inside the function')
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var now = new Date();
    var week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
    var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl;
    var signatureUTF8 = Buffer.from(signature, 'utf8');
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', saKey).update(signatureUTF8).digest('base64');
    return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +
        encodeURIComponent(hash) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName;
}*
```

Its a POST call with Authorization and Content-Type header.

Comment: Can you please add the Url?

Comment: Here it is: https://<mynamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<my-topic-name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add 'messages' at the end of the url:

http{s}://{serviceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{queuePath|topicPath}/messages

->
https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/my-topic-name/messages

[Send Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue)